# Loop Through All Elements that Meet Criteria

Tags: javascript

In vanilla JS, I'm trying to set a property for all "li"s that have certain parents under a specific class.

Basically if it meets ".qa ul li" then set the tabindex to 0.

Right now I'm using:

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('li').length; i++){
    if(????) document.getElementsByTagName('li')[i].tabIndex = 0;
    }
```

My problem is I don't know how to see if that specific "li" is under a a "ul" under a "qa" class.

And if I were to get it, would a different approach be better? I have a lot of "li"s and not all meet my criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `getElementsByTagName()`, you can use `querySelectorAll()`:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.qa ul li');

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].tabIndex = 0;
}
```

This will select only the `<li>` elements that you're looking for - no need for conditional logic.

I've also combined your repeated DOM searches into one variable. Instead of searching the DOM to initialize the `for` and then for each subsequent iteration, you only need *one* DOM search.

---

**Example:**

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.qa ul li');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].style.color = 'red';
}
```

```html
<div class="qa">
  Parent has QA class:
  <ul>
    <li>TEST</li>
    <li>TEST</li>
    <li>TEST</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div>
  Parent does not have QA class:
  <ul>
    <li>TEST</li>
    <li>TEST</li>
    <li>TEST</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This would also highlight an `<li>` in: `<div class="qa"><ul><li><div class="not-qa"><ul><li>...` That's why I recommended `.qa > ul > li`

Comment: I simply used the selector that OP supplied in his question.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that *facepalm*

Comment: All good. I'm not saying you're incorrect - I'm inclined to agree with your assumption. I just chose to keep it as OP requested.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in your code that scare me, and you should be aware of the performance implications. Firstly:

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('li').length; i++)
```

This means you are executing `document.getElementsByTagName('li').length` [every time you increment `i`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), and querying the DOM is an expensive operation to perform. Instead, you should do:

```
for(var i = 0, length = document.getElementsByTagName('li').length; i < length; i++)
```

Same thing goes for the `document.getElementsByTagName('li')[i]` inside the `if` statement, but as the comment pointed out, you don't need the `if` if you use a [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with the right selector:

```
var li = document.querySelectorAll('.qa ul li');

for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li[i].tabIndex = 0;
}
```

In this code, the `querySelector()` is executed only once, and only the inexpensive `.length` property reference is used for each iteration of `i`.